# Child class method calling parent class ordinary method in Python

Tags: python

Consider the following snippet in Python:

```
class A:
    def f(self, arg):
        print(self, arg)

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def f(cls, arg):
        super(B, cls).f(arg)
        print(cls, arg)

B.f(1)
```

I know it's wrong to write like this, but I'm trying to understand what's going on behind the scenes. Why do I need to pass the first argument explicitly in call to inherited function? If this snippet is run, I get an exception that the required positional argument was not provided.

When I call `B.f(1)`, the first argument (the class `B`) is passed implicitly. I thought the same should be the case when I call the inherited ordinary method through class instance: `self` should be class `B`.

Is it some interpreter magic - say, it looks at class `A`, sees that `f` is ordinary function there, and does not set the first argument implicitly because it's called as class method?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code successfully by simply changing

```
super (B, cls).f(arg)
```

to:

```
super (B, cls).f (cls, arg)
```

and it worked fine. I guess the class **isn't** passed implicitly.

Comment: But the class is passed implicitly when calling class method. Do you know when it's passed implicitly and when it's not?

Comment: Apparently, here it isn't! I assume this pattern holds for calling functions of OTHER classes